# Is the syntax $\lim_{\phi(h)\to a} f(\phi(h))=L$ informal? Or does $\phi(h) \to a$ have a precise definition/extension of the standard limit syntax?

Tags: calculus, limits, logic, proof-explanation

I am hoping that someone can clearly explain to me what exactly the following notation is shorthand for:

> $\displaystyle \lim_{\phi(h)\to a} f(\phi(h))=L \quad (\dagger)$

Because of the first order logic interpretation of the limits...i.e. $\displaystyle\lim_{y \to 0}f(y)=\mathcal k \iff \forall \varepsilon \gt 0: \exists \delta \gt 0: \forall y \in (-\delta,\delta)\setminus{\{0\}}:|f(y)-\mathcal k| \lt \varepsilon$...it's not clear to me what is meant in the above instance (I would think that we are *not* universally quantifying over the symbol "$\phi(h)$"...as I am not certain that this is logically valid...but maybe it is?)

Is this, in fact, an informal notation? Or does it have a *specific* definition...some extension of the aforementioned form when we have a single symbol (e.g. "$y$")?

---

Regarding the general form written in $(\dagger)$,  it seems as though an implicit assumption is that the function $\phi$ approaches $a$. i.e. there is some $\gamma$ such that $\displaystyle \lim_{h \to \gamma}\phi(h)=a$. If we can solve for $\gamma$, then $(\dagger)$ seems essentially equivalent to:

> $\displaystyle \lim_{h \to \gamma}f(\phi(h))=L \quad (*)$

Is this the correct interpretation?

What happens if $\phi$ does *not* approach $a$? Does that render the syntax $\displaystyle \lim_{\phi(h)\to a} f(\phi(h))$ all together invalid?

---

For example, consider the author-provided solution to Problem 32 of Chapter 18 of Spivak's *Calculus* (which clearly wants us to assume, without proof, that $\lim_{k  \to 0}(1+k)^{\frac{1}{k}} \in (0,\infty)$...otherwise, the final step of his proof cannot be carried out). The $(\dagger)$ comes in to play at the $\color{red}{\text{red}}$ equal sign

> \begin{align}\log'_a(x)&=\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{\log_a(x+h)-\log_a(x)}{h} \\&=\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{\log_a\left(\frac{x+h}{x}\right)}{h}=\lim_{h \to 0}\log_a\left[\left(1+\frac{h}{x}\right)^{\frac{1}{h}}\right] \\&\color{red}{=}\lim_{\frac{h}{x}\to 0}\log_a\left[\left(1+\frac{h}{x}\right)^{\frac{x}{h}\cdot\frac{1}{x}}\right]=\lim_{k \to 0}\log_a\left[\left(1+k\right)^{\frac{1}{k}\cdot\frac{1}{x}}\right]\\&=\lim_{k \to 0}\frac{1}{x}\log_a\left[\left(1+k\right)^{\frac{1}{k}}\right]=\frac{1}{x}\lim_{k \to 0}\log_a\left[\left(1+k\right)^{\frac{1}{k}}\right]\\&=\frac{1}{x}\log_a\left(\lim_{k \to 0}(1+k)^{\frac{1}{k}}\right) \quad\text{By continuity of $\log_a$}\end{align}

---

**I came up with my own proof** that does not make use of the "$\displaystyle\lim_{\frac{h}{x}\to 0}$" notation by considering three different functions $F$, $G$, and $\phi$ together with some standard limit rules:

$F(\cdot)=\log_a\left[\left(1+\frac{(\cdot)}{x}\right)^{\frac{1}{(\cdot)}}\right]$, where $x \gt 0$

$\displaystyle G(\cdot)=\log_a\left[\big(1+(\cdot)\big)^{\frac{1}{(\cdot)} \times \frac{1}{x}}\right ]$ where $x \gt 0$

$\phi(\cdot)=\frac{(\cdot)}{x}$ where $x \gt 0$

Note that $F(\cdot)=G \circ \phi(\cdot)$, which means that $\displaystyle\lim_{h \to 0}F(h)=\lim_{h \to 0} G \circ \phi(h) $. In accordance to what I wrote in $(*)$, because $\displaystyle \lim_{h \to 0}\phi(h)=0$, $\displaystyle \lim_{h \to 0}G \circ \phi(h)$ can be (if I so chose) *rewritten* as $\displaystyle\lim_{\phi(h)\to 0}G(\phi(h))$. I go on to show that $\displaystyle \lim_{h \to 0}G\circ \phi(h)=\lim_{h \to 0} G(h)$, which appears to be exactly what Spivak ultimately did.

If this is what Spivak means by "$\displaystyle \lim_{\frac{h}{x}\to 0}$", I really do not see the point of this notation. It seems to obfuscate what is actually going on.

Comment: If they had taken the limit as $h \to c$ for some appropriate $c$, then I would say that the expression had a formal meaning as you have explored. But because it is $\phi(h)$ that approaches $a$, the only reasonable interpretation I can see is $$L = \lim_{\underset{y \in \text{Dom}(\phi)}{y \to a}} f(y)$$ and even then, I would say there is an implicit assumption that $a$ is an accumulation point of $\text{Dom}(\phi)$, since the limit is ill-defined otherwise.

Comment: In the case of your example from Spivak, yes, he is clearly using this informally as an intermediary in the variable substitution he is making $k = \frac hx$. The sole purpose is the clarify the substitution without his having to break the equation in order to insert explanatory text.